# How do I block an abusive IP address using a Netgear FVS338 firewall?

Tags: firewall, netgear, ip-blocking

Our Postfix mailserver has been getting thousands of automated login attempts from a bot. The mailserver is behind a Netgear FVS338 firewall.

How can I completely block inbound connections from that IP address using the Netgear FVS338 firewall?

I added the following Inbound Service rule but it appeared to have no effect as the Postfix log still kept showing failed login entries. (I have obfuscated the IP address)

[image]

[image]

These are the entries in /var/log/mail.info that brought it to my attention. (IP address changed to 1.2.3.4 when posting here)

```
Aug 27 14:33:52 mail pop3d: Maximum connection limit reached for ::ffff:1.2.3.4
Aug 27 14:33:52 mail pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=anthony, ip=[::ffff:1.2.3.4]
Aug 27 14:33:52 mail pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=antonio, ip=[::ffff:1.2.3.4]
Aug 27 14:33:52 mail pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=anon, ip=[::ffff:1.2.3.4]
Aug 27 14:33:52 mail pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=andrei, ip=[::ffff:1.2.3.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your rule is on the bottom of the list.  I believe Netgear uses order of precedence when applying firewall rules.

http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/FVS338_RM_28Jan2010.pdf  - Page 4-8

Try moving it up above "Allow All" if there is one.

If that doesn't fix it, you can use IPsec / IPTables on the server itself as a quick remedy.

Comment: Thanks I did end up using this as a temporary workaround.
iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP I will check out the order of precedence thing next time I'm at the site.

Comment: http://documentation.netgear.com/dg834n/enu/202-10197-02/Firewall.5.4.html#48121